# How to write a simple tree to file and read it back?

Tags: c

I have some code to create a simple tree based on pointers to nodes, and would like to write this tree (with its data) to a file and than read it back from file into memory. How can I do this ? Here is my code to create a simple tree:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

struct Node 
{ 
    void *data; 

    struct Node *left; 
    struct Node *right;
};

int main(void) 
{ 
    unsigned int_size = sizeof(int);
    int data;

    /* Tree root node */
    struct Node *start = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    data = 5;

    start->data = malloc(int_size);
    memcpy(start->data, &data, int_size);

    /* Left node of root */
    start->left = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    data = 4;

    start->left->data = malloc(int_size);
    memcpy(start->left->data, &data, int_size);

    start->left->left = NULL;
    start->left->right = NULL;

    /* Right node of root */
    start->right = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    data = 3;

    start->right->data = malloc(int_size);
    memcpy(start->right->data, &data, int_size);

    start->right->left = NULL;
    start->right->right = NULL;

    /* Print data */

    printf("%d\n",*(int*)(start->data));
    printf("%d\n",*(int*)(start->left->data));
    printf("%d\n",*(int*)(start->right->data));

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858). And `sizeof` return a value of type `size_t`.

Comment: I'm not printing a pointer, but the content of the pointee.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that dereference.

Comment: void *data is meant for the tree being able to use any data (integer, float, struct, etc.)

Comment: Now for your problem, that's actually not trivial. You might want to do some research about [*serialiozation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), and then perhaps find a library which handles it for you.

Comment: Can we assume that the tree will only contain one single data type at a time?

Comment: Hmmm.... if you only need the content of each element, it is just a matter of traversing recursively (and pass a filepointer in the call). However that will then just store all the elements and not the structure of the tree. Do you need to store the structure of the tree as well?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta yes we can assume 1 single data type at a time. Thanks

Comment: Øystein Schønning-Johansen I my case I would like to have the structure of the tree in the file as well as I would like to update the code in the future for other structures as well where it is not straightforward to just write the data in the nodes to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a proposal, I use preprocessor macro TYPE to be able to change type and separated functions to read/write an element of that type, I also use function *mk* to easily create node rather than to duplicate the code as you did for each node.

For the serialization I use a very simple way

- 'e' indicates an empty node
- 'n' indicate a non empty node, then I write the value then the left then the right node

I also added *pr* to easily print a tree as a debug function.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define TYPE int

struct Node 
{ 
  TYPE data; 

  struct Node *left; 
  struct Node *right;
};

/* make a new Node */
struct Node * mk(TYPE v, struct Node * l, struct Node * r)
{
  struct Node * n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  if (n == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "not enough memory\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  n->data = v;
  n->left = l;
  n->right = r;

  return n;
}

/* write/read data */
void wrData(TYPE v, FILE * fp)
{
  fprintf(fp, "%d", v); /* dedicated to int */
}

TYPE rdData(FILE * fp)
{
  TYPE v;

  fscanf(fp, "%d", &v); /* dedicated to int */
  return v;
}

/* serialize a tree */
void wr(struct Node * n, FILE * fp)
{
  if (n == NULL)
    fputc('e', fp);
  else {
    fputc('n', fp);
    wrData(n->data, fp);
    wr(n->left, fp);
    wr(n->right, fp);
  }
}

/* unserialize a tree */
struct Node * rd(FILE * fp)
{
  switch (fgetc(fp)) {
  case 'e':
    return NULL;
  case 'n':
    {
      TYPE v = rdData(fp);
      struct Node * l = rd(fp);

      return mk(v, l, rd(fp));
    }
  default:
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid file");
    exit(-1);
  }
}

/* for debug, show tree */
void pr(struct Node * t)
{
  if (t == NULL)
    printf("()");
  else {
    putchar('(');
    pr(t->left);
    putchar(' ');
    wrData(t->data, stdout);
    putchar(' ');
    pr(t->right);
    putchar(')');
  }
}

/* free a tree */
void del(struct Node * t)
{
  if (t != NULL) {
    del(t->left);
    del(t->right);
    free(t);
  }
}

int main() 
{ 
    /* Tree root node */
    struct Node *start = mk(5, mk(4, NULL, NULL), mk(3, NULL, NULL));

    /* show it */
    pr(start);
    putchar('\n');

    /* serialize */
    FILE * fp;

    if ((fp = fopen("/tmp/t", "w")) == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, " cannot open /tmp/t to write");
      exit(-1);
    }
    wr(start, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    /* free tree */
    del(start);

    /* unserialize */
    if ((fp = fopen("/tmp/t", "r")) == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, " cannot open /tmp/t to read");
      exit(-1);
    }
    start = rd(fp);
    fclose(fp);

    /* show it */
    pr(start);
    putchar('\n');

    /* free it */
    del(start);

    return 0; 
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall t.c
/tmp % ./a.out
((() 4 ()) 5 (() 3 ()))
((() 4 ()) 5 (() 3 ()))
/tmp % cat t ; echo
n5n4een3ee
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
/tmp % valgrind ./a.out
==19907== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19907== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19907== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19907== Command: ./a.out
==19907== 
((() 4 ()) 5 (() 3 ()))
((() 4 ()) 5 (() 3 ()))
==19907== 
==19907== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19907==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19907==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 1,280 bytes allocated
==19907== 
==19907== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19907== 
==19907== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19907== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: Thanks @bruno. It helped me alot! Learned lots of things in your code. Thanks again

Comment: just a question, why use `struct Node * n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` ? I thought result of malloc is `void*`. Why no casts ?

Comment: @Meerkat you cancel the accept on my answer, why do you ask me ?

Comment: oh did I cancel something ? Is it maybe because I also accepted another solution, and that your solution got cancelled automatically ? Because that would not be the intention as I really liked your solution.

Comment: I accepted your answer again, but now the acceptance of @Serge Ballesta got cancelled. I like to accept both answers. How can I do that ?

Comment: @Meerkat you cannot accept several, the only thing you can do in that case is to accept your preferred answer and to upvote the other answers you like (you can also upvote the preferred one of course)

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways for serializing objects having pointers on other objects. First one is to replace the pointer with an offset in the file, second one is to use a simple index. In fact, the offset way is mainly used when the data is used directly from the file (database files for example) while the index way is more used for simple storage.

Here a simple way would be to store the nodes into a file recursively as left_node - right_node - main_node. That way when you store a node you already know the index in the file of its left and right children. A possible implementation is then:

```
static size_t do_save(FILE *fd, struct Node *node, unsigned data_size, int curr) {
    size_t left=0, right=0;
    if (node->left != NULL) {   // first left sub_hierarchy
        left = do_save(fd, node->left, data_size, curr);
        curr = left;
    }
    if (node->left != NULL) {   // then right one
        right = do_save(fd, node->right, data_size, curr);
        curr = right;
    }
    fwrite(&left, sizeof(left), 1, fd);       // store index of left child
    fwrite(&right, sizeof(right), 1, fd);     // then index of right child
    fwrite(node->data, data_size, 1, fd);     // then the data
    return curr + 1;                          // and return current index
}
size_t save(FILE *fd, struct Node *root, unsigned data_size) {
    size_t nb = do_save(fd, root, data_size, 0);
    return nb;
}
```

Here, an index of 0 means a null pointer, and a non null index is a one based index in the file

To deserialize, as I assume that you want each node to be individually allocated, I would use a temporary array of pointers to keep the actual addresses of the allocated nodes:

```
struct Node* load(FILE *fd, unsigned data_size) {
    size_t nb_elts, left, right;
    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);                // computer number of nodes in the file
    nb_elts = ftell(fd) / (data_size + 2*sizeof(size_t));
    struct Node** ptx = malloc(nb_elts * sizeof(*ptx));  // allocate array of pointers
    fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for(size_t i=0; i<nb_elts; i++) {                    // loop reading nodes
        ptx[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));            // allocate node and data
        ptx[i]->data = malloc(data_size);
        fread(&left, sizeof(size_t), 1, fd);             // extract child indices
        fread(&right, sizeof(size_t), 1, fd);
        fread(ptx[i]->data, data_size, 1, fd);                 // read data
        ptx[i]->left = (left == 0) ? NULL : ptx[left - 1];     // convert indices to pointers
        ptx[i]->right = (right == 0) ? NULL : ptx[right - 1];
    }
    struct Node *last = ptx[nb_elts - 1];
    free(ptx);                                     // free the temporary array
    return last;                                   // and return the root node
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Serge Ballesta. I find the code rather difficult to understand, but I will experiment with it to get to understand the working of it better :)

Comment: apparently if one accepts a solution, than other solutions cannot be accepted. So I accepted bruno's solution first, than yours, but than bruno's acceptance got automatically cancelled. So I accepted his solution again as he was first (chronologically). I hope you don't mind!

Comment: No problem for me... Bruno needs more rep than I do :-)

Comment: Ok nice to hear you understand. As I said, I also like your solution very much, so I’m going to experiment with your code. Thanks again!